# How to add column name inside Excel file?

Tags: android

I'm new to android can you tell me How to add column name in excel file.

Currently I'm doing sqlite to excel and for this I have to generate report in the form of excel. I'm successfully done with this but can't add column names, Please refer my code and tell me what should I write.

```
 private void exportStockReport() {

    ReportToExcel reportToExcel;
    List<Products> productsList = db.getAllProducts();

    List<List<String>> reportList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
   //What should i add here to add colounm name in excel file
    for (Products p : productsList) {
        List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();

        columnList.add(p.getName());
        columnList.add(String.valueOf(p.getLowStock()));
        columnList.add(String.valueOf(p.getStock()));
        reportList.add(columnList);
    }
    reportToExcel = new ReportToExcel(ReportActivity.this, "Products Stock", directory_path);
    reportToExcel.exportReport(reportList, "Stock Report.xls", new ReportToExcel.ExportListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(String filePath) {
            Toast.makeText(ReportActivity.this, "Stock Report Successfully Exported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ReportActivity.this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Comment: which library are you using for ReportToExcel?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `columnList.add("column1");`  What library you use for ReportToExcel?